# Git Repository Cloning Error (terminal prompts disabled)

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using 15.4.5 version of Visual Studio Enterprise and version 2.15.0 for GIT. I am trying to clone my repo from VSTS but I am getting an error which is mentioned below. Do you have any solution for that problem?

***Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://xxx.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that problem myself. There was some misconfiguration regarding GIT, i think. It was preventing pop-ups. So, if you re-install GIT on your local machine, everything's gonna be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue guys, it appears when I have only TLS1.2 enabled on my PC. After enabling TLS 1.1, SSL.x the issue was resolved. For enabling and disabling I used IISCrypto software. Hope that helps others.